# Calculate Grand Total from sub-total

Tags: jquery

I have a table of sub-totals.

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><span id="subtotal_1">100</span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><span id="subtotal_2">150</span></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my Javascript code to calculate grand total :

```
var grandtotal = 0;
$('span[id^=subtotal_]').each(function() {
    grandtotal += parseInt($(this).val());
});
```

but the `grandtotal` returns nothing. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) here, [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is for input fields

```
var grandtotal = 0;
$('span[id^=subtotal_]').each(function() {
    grandtotal += parseInt($.trim($(this).text()));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e5Rcz/)

Comment: oops, I overlooked this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

just change the .val() to .text()

```
var grandtotal = 0;
$('span[id^=subtotal_]').each(function() {
    grandtotal += parseInt($(this).text());
});
```